# Rename files in ascending order using a counter BASH

Tags: bash

I have several .jpg images in a folder that have names like:

```
20140331_134927.jpg
20140331_124933.jpg
20140331_124933.jpg
etc..
```

I want to rename them to something like:

```
Agra-1.jpg
Agra-2.jpg
Agra-3.jpg
etc..
```

I tried running the following script (stored as my.sh):

```
for files in *.jpg; do
    i=1
    echo mv "$files" "Agra-$i.jpg"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

However, if I were to run that without the echo, all files would be renamed to "Agra-1.jpg"

Why does this not work as I expect and how should this be written?

Comment: You say `i=1` __within__ the loop.

Comment: I expected the file names to be incremented as displayed above.

Comment: With 1K+ rep, you seem to be trolling now.  If you __assign__ a variable within a loop, how would you expect it be incremented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the assignment out of the loop:

```
i=1    # only once
for files in *.jpg; do
    mv "$files" "Agra-$i.jpg"
    let i++
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example - you should declare the counter variable outside of the loop otherwise it will be reset to its initial value on each iteration:

Inside loop:

```
$ for file in *; do i=1; echo $i; (( i++ )); done
1
1
1
```

Outside loop:

```
$ i=1
$ for file in *; do echo $i; (( i++ )); done
1
2
3
```